# Why does plot between same scaled and unscaled data look different?

Tags: data-visualization, normalization

I am using the `StandardScaler` of [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to scale my data. When plotting the data and comparing scaled with unscaled I get different results in how the plots look like. I expect that the plot of the unscaled data looks like that one of the scaled one but instead they look really different. Why is that the case? I thought during scaling the relations between the data are still the same.

**Unscaled data**

$value_1 = 1011.96875, value_2 = 1011.87500, value_3 = 1011.78125 ... value_{1000} = 937.43750$

[image]

**Scaled data**

$value_1 = -0.468095, value_2 = -0.258494, value_3 = -0.191027 ... value_{1000} = -0.028573$

[image]

**Code for scaling**

```py
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = get_data_unscaled()
test_x = pd.DataFrame(test_x)
test_y = pd.DataFrame(test_y)
train_x = pd.DataFrame(train_x)
train_y = pd.DataFrame(train_y)
scalerX = StandardScaler().fit(train_x)
scalerY = StandardScaler().fit(train_y)
train_x = scalerX.transform(train_x)
train_y = scalerY.transform(train_y)
test_x = scalerX.transform(test_x)
test_y = scalerY.transform(test_y)
```

where `train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y` is the unscaled data.

Comment: The labels on the horizontal axes are completely different in the two plots. Are you sure that both plots these show the same data?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Max Hager. Can you tell us what mathematical function your are referring to with the word "scaled"? Often time "scaled" means multiplied by some number (e.g., the reciprocal of the standard deviation is a common scaling factor). However, if you are using "scaled" to mean some mathematically more complex transformation, it will help your audience, including @Sycorax , to understand your question better. (You can click "edit" in the lower left of your question to add that information.)

Comment: The documentation says z = (x - u) / s. @Alexis

Comment: This is what confuses me. Will double check. @Sycorax

Comment: Can you plot scaled vs unscaled? Should be linear on your story.

Comment: If I had to guess what happened, I think that the second plot is produced from 2 transformations: (1) first-differences and (2) standard scalar. The first plot shows a drop off on the left and "leveling off" to the right, and the second plot shows steep values on the left and values near zero on the right.

Comment: What do you mean? I plotted it already. I guess you are confused because I do not show all 1000 values or? I plot 1000 values which I tried to demonstrate with the three dots `...`. @NickCox

Comment: I just use standard scaler. I added the code for it. What do you mean by first differences? @Sycorax

Comment: Nick Cox's comment is exactly correct: if the scaled vs unscaled data plot is not a straight line, then you applied some additional transformations. The plots don't show the unscaled data plotted against the scaled data, they show the scaled data plotted against a sequence of integers and the unscaled data plotted against a series of strings. The code is not completely helpful because it doesn't show how you made the plots. First-differences compute 1-step changes: $\Delta x = x_{t+1} - x_t$.

Comment: Max Hager, I think @NickCox means plot scaled data on the $y$ axis, and unscaled data on the $x$ axis. Because the z score is an affine transformation, there should be a 1-to-1 correspondence of both points and distances on scaled and unscaled, so that what you should see on this plot is all values falling exactly on a straight line (Just as I am now seeing Sycorax as provided an answer about :).

Comment: Others are reading my comment as intended. I don't know what else unscaled versus scaled could mean. As I understand it the horizontal axis in the graphs displayed is some kind of sequence or time variable. Supplying say the first 200 values should be quite sufficient to allow independent tests. I don't use this software, sorry, but I think those who do need access to the data; otherwise the thread is of limited value to anyone without scope for a check.  As yet another puzzling detail, I wouldn't expect standardized values to fall in so narrow a range.

Answer (score 4):

Nick Cox's comment is exactly correct. The sklearn StandardScalar computes new variables that have the mean $\mu$ subtracted and are divided by the standard deviation $\sigma > 0$:
$$\begin{align}
\tilde x &= \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \\
&= \sigma^{-1}x - \sigma^{-1}\mu
\end{align}
$$
Recall that the equation of a line is $y=ax+b$, so we have $a = \sigma^{-1}$ and $b =- \sigma^{-1}\mu$. Thus, $\tilde x$ is a linear function of $x$, so a plot of $(x,\tilde x)$ should form a straight line.

If the plot of scaled data $\tilde x$ vs unscaled data $x$ is not a straight line, then you've made a mistake somewhere in your code (perhaps you applied some additional transformations, or are comparing two different series of data, or you plotted the wrong data, or you used the wrong plotting options).

If you're using Jupyter Notebooks, I think the most plausible source of error is that you've run the cells in an unexpected order.